# Webpack cannot find keymirror module with Typescript import

Tags: import, module, typescript, reactjs, webpack

I'm using Typescript, React, and Webpack and struggling to import the keymirror module.

I am using the [latest version of typescript](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2015/07/27/introducing-typescript-nightlies.aspx).

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "Fun",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Dear Webpack Gods, please help.",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "eventemitter3": "^1.1.1",
    "flux": "^2.0.3",
    "keymirror": "^0.1.1",
    "react": "^0.13.3",
    "ts-loader": "^0.5.0",
    "typescript": "^1.6.0-dev.20150812"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^0.16.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.12.3"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './App/app.tsx',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.tsx', '.ts']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.ts(x?)$/, loader: 'ts-loader' },
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader' }
        ]
    }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "jsx": "react",
        "sourceMap": true
    },
    "files": [
        "./typings/tsd.d.ts",
        "./App/app.tsx"
    ]
}
```

The offending import is located in ./User/Constants.ts

```
import keyMirror = require('keymirror');

export = keyMirror({
    LOGIN_ATTEMPT: null
});
```

I have tried using the [standalone npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/keymirror) as seen above, as well as attempting to require it from react/lib/keyMirror.

Any ideas?

(**EDIT**: Yes, I know it's a 12 line module that I could just copy into my code.)

**Solution from Basarat (with slight modification)**

```
declare module 'keymirror' {
    function keyMirror(obj: Object);
    export = keyMirror;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> import keyMirror = require('keymirror');

You need to tell typescript about it. Basically something like :

```
declare module 'keymirror' {
   var export:any;
   export = export;
}
```

In a file called `global.d.ts`.

Some docs : http://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/ambient/intro.html

Comment: Thanks @basarat. a slight modification to this worked well.If you don't want to modify it, you can always convert the module to typescript and then it wont complain